# Nested Excel IF function

Tags: excel

Okay, currently I have an if statement that looks like this:
=IF(AND(OR(K2<>K3,L2<>L3),A2=A3),A2,"")

My issue is that in column K, I want to take off a few characters. I'd like to write this function: Left(K2, LEN(K2)-2)

I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the if statement though. Any ideas?

Comment: Clarification: I'd like to take the characters off of *both* K cells (so both K2 and K3), so that I'm only comparing the first two characters in K with each other.

Example: in cell K2 is P2.A, in K3 is P2.Z  I want the if statement to only pull in values that are different in the first two characters. So only if K2 is A2.A and K3 is P2.Z.

Comment: Pretty simple replacement: `=IF(AND(OR(Left(K2, LEN(K2)-2)<>Left(K3, LEN(K3)-2),L2<>L3),A2=A3),A2,"")`

Comment: If it is only the first two characters then I would use `LEFT(K2,2)`. it is less typing and more exact.

Comment: Dang you guys are fast with your responses/comments.   You had all the information Phlegon, you just had to substitute you second formula into your first and update the cell references for when you substituted for the K3 cell.   Breaking a formula down into its various parts and then back substituting to make a big formula in one cell is not bad practice as you get to check that each part of your formula is working as intended.  much easier to trouble shoot small formulas than big convoluted monstrosities after all.